# Error "xxxx"does not name a type

Tags: c++, types

I encountered a problem when tried compiling the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

map<char, int> mapDial;

mapDial['A'] = 2;

int main()
{

  cout << mapDial['A'] << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The compiler gave me a error: 'mapDial' does not name a type error. I am new to c++ and really don't know what is going on here. Can anyone here help me to solve this? Thanks!!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You cannot execute arbitrary expressions at global scope, so

```
mapDial['A'] = 2;
```

is illegal. If you have C++11, you can do

```
map<char, int> mapDial {
    { 'A', 2 }
};
```

But if you don't, you'll have to call an initialisation function from `main` to set it up the way you want it. You can also look into the constructor of `map` that takes an iterator, and use that with an array in a function to initialise the map, e.g.

```
map<char, int> initMap() {
    static std::pair<char, int> data[] = {
        std::pair<char, int>('A', 2)
    };

    return map<char, int>(data, data + sizeof(data) / sizeof(*data));
}

map<char, int> mapDial = initMap();
```

Answer (score 5):

When you declare a variable in global scope, you may only do initialization. E.g,

```
int a = 0;
```

You cannot do normal statements like:

```
a = 9;
```

So I would fix the code with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

map<char, int> mapDial;

int main()
{
  mapDial['A'] = 2;
  cout << mapDial['A'] << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't have statements like `mapDial['A'] = 2;` at global scope. They must be inside a function.